# Why is MAX() not showing the highest number?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having an issue with MAX() on postgres.

With the following data set:

```
Batch Number
1
2
3
```

When I query this:

```
SELECT "Batch Number" FROM tbl WHERE "Batch Number" = (select max("Batch Number") from tbl)
```

I get the correct value (3)

But when I manually insert a batch number of 10000 and run the same query it still shows 3 as the highest number when it should be 10000

```
Batch Number
1
2
3
10000
```

Comment: Is this a `VARCHAR` column? If so `3` sorts ahead of anything starting with `1`.

Comment: @tadman No the field is a text field. I tried 20000 to see if it helped but still getting the same results.

Comment: @tadman hmm actually I think it has to do with the first number like you mentioned. When I did 20000 it brought it in the middle. When I try for example 9000 it works. Do I need to convert the field into a integer field for it to sort properly? It's most likely the field type causing this.

Comment: If you want numerical max, just change the column type from text to int. You can simply try to see what will be happening when the column type is int, just try max(cast(ColumnName as int))

Comment: If you're sorting *numerically* you absolutely need an integer field otherwise it's done ASCIIabetically, as in by first letter, then second letter...

Answer (score 5):

If you're sorting *numerically* you absolutely need an integer field otherwise it's done ASCIIabetically, as in by first letter, then second letter.

This means your sort order is like in a dictionary, as in:

```
1
10000
2
20000
3
90000
```

Where only the first digit matters unless there's a tie. Look at the output of `SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY` on that column.

> Note that column names with spaces in them are super annoying and should be avoided. Just use an underscore, or like `batchno` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are using a subquery for this.  You want a numeric sort, so you can cast.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT "Batch Number"
FROM tbl
ORDER BY "Batch Number"::numeric DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `::numeric` is the secret sauce that did it for me, it wasn't clear exactly what jsonb was returning at all times, and the cast forced the order by to recognize 10 as greater than 9.

Answer (score 0):

***You can use oracle/plsql***

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_NUMBER(Batch_Number)))
FROM tbl
```